# How to build custom circle range in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kISNP.png)
How to implement it in Flutter?

Comment: Use `CustomPainter` and all you need is `drawXXX` method.

Comment: hm, ok, I will try

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/introducing-radial-gauge-widget-in-flutter.aspx might help